# How do i solve UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username problem in Django

Tags: django, unique-constraint

I am brand new to Django.
I made a register form.
One time out of two, when i try to register a new user i have an exception "auth_user.username"
it seems there is no rule, it can works many times in a row and with new user registration i have the error!

Here is my form.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm,AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from bootstrap_modal_forms.mixins import PopRequestMixin, CreateUpdateAjaxMixin
from django import forms

 class CustomUserCreationForm(PopRequestMixin, CreateUpdateAjaxMixin,
                         UserCreationForm):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
def clean_email(self):
    if User.objects.filter(email=self.cleaned_data['email']).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError("the given email is already registered")
    return self.cleaned_data['email']
```

'''

views.py

```
enter code here

from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from bootstrap_modal_forms.generic import BSModalCreateView,BSModalLoginView
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm,CustomAuthenticationForm

class SignUpView(BSModalCreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    template_name = 'signup.html'
    success_message = 'Success: Sign up succeeded. You can now Log in.'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
```

signup.html

```
enter code here
{% load widget_tweaks %}
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384- 
  q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" 
  integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" 
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
   integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" 
   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".site-navbar-target" data-offset="300">

   <form method="post" action="">
   {% csrf_token %}

   <div class="modal-header">
     <h3 class="modal-title">Register</h3>
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
     </button>
   </div>
```

```
<div class="{% if form.non_field_errors %}invalid{% endif %} mb-2">
  {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
    {{ error }}
  {% endfor %}
</div>

{% for field in form %}
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
    {% render_field field class="form-control" placeholder=field.label %}
    <div class="{% if field.errors %} invalid{% endif %}">
      {% for error in field.errors %}
        <p class="help-block" style="color:red">{{ error }}</p>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Register

THANK YOU

Comment: As the error indicates, that is because you create a user with a username that is already "taken" (there is a user with that username already).

Comment: @steph you can check my answer

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Hello, no, even if the username is not taken i have this error.

Comment: @steph: perhaps the username you submit is "lost" somewhere, such that you end up, each time using an "empty" username so to speak.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it is impossibile, each time i try with a quite different username

Answer (score 0):

I remember two ways we can accomplish that:

1. Override the User model's save method and only try to save if the object does not exist:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not User.objects.filter(name=self.name).first():
        super(User, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

2. Create your custom model and inherit from User, and drop the unique constraint:

```
    class CustomUser(User):
        username = models.CharField(_("User name"), max_length=30, blank=False)
```

This way you have more control of your validations.